# Rails - calling partial from one controller in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carmen

I am trying to select a country and its region in a form to the db.  I have a form that appears in sessions#new action of the view but is located in `access_requests/_form.html.slim`.  It posts to access_requests#create.  In the form I have a `subregion_select` partial in the views/sessions folder.  Everything works fine except when I post the form I get the following error message:

```
Missing partial access_requests/_subregion_select
```

**access_requests/_form.html.slim**

```
= simple_form_for object, url: access_requests_path do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.input :first_name, input_html: { class: "form-control" }
  ...
  = f.simple_fields_for :extra_attributes do |extra_fields|
  .form-group
    = extra_fields.input :country, as: :select, collection: site_countries, prompt: 'Please select a country', label: "Franchisee Billing Country", input_html: { class: "form-control" }
    .form-group
    = label_tag "Franchisee Billing State/Province"
    = render partial: "subregion_select"
```

**_subregion_select.html.slim**

```
#states_provinces_wrapper
  - country_code ||= params[:country_code]
  - country = Carmen::Country.coded(country_code)

  - if country.nil?
    em Please select a country above
  - else
    = select "access_request_form[extra_attributes]", "province", states_provinces_for_select(country_code), class: "form-control"
```

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#access_request_form_extra_attributes_country').change(function(event) {
    var country_code, select_wrapper, url;
    select_wrapper = $('#states_provinces_wrapper');
    $('select', select_wrapper).attr('disabled', true);
    country_code = $(this).val();
    url = "/subregion_options?country_code=" + country_code;
    select_wrapper.load(url);
  });
});
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
def subregion_options
  render partial: "subregion_select"
end
```

Comment: After posting the form with success and upon redirection you are getting that error?

Answer (score 1):

Use the partial's full path (relative to app/views) instead:

```
render partial: "sessions/subregion_select"
```